# Can not run the macro xx. may not be available in this workbook or all macros are disabled

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, vba

I am trying to execute the following code

```
const string excelFile = @"C:\test.xls";

                var excelApplication = new ExcelInterop.Application { Visible = true };
                var targetExcelFile = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFile,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                var newStandardModule = targetExcelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
                var codeModule = newStandardModule.CodeModule;

                // add vba code to module
                var lineNum = codeModule.CountOfLines + 1;
                var macroName = "test";
                var codeText = " Sub " + macroName + "()" + "\r\n";
                codeText += " Dim xsheet As Worksheet" + "\r\n";
                codeText += "For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" + "\r\n";
                codeText += " xsheet.Select" + "\r\n";
                codeText += "With xsheet.UsedRange" + "\r\n";
                codeText += "    .Value = .Value" + "\r\n";
                codeText += "  End With" + "\r\n";
                codeText += "Next xsheet    " + "\r\n";
                codeText += "End Sub";

                codeModule.InsertLines(lineNum, codeText);
                targetExcelFile.Save();

                // run the macro
                var macro = string.Format("{0}!{1}.{2}", targetExcelFile.Name, newStandardModule.Name, macroName);
                excelApplication.Run(macro,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,  
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,  
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,  
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,  
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,  
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
);
                excelApplication.Quit();
```

I always got the following error

> "Can not run the macro xx. may not be available in this workbook or all
>   macros are disabled."

How to resolve the error? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have other instances of Excel open?

Comment: 1) What is your macro security setting in Excel? 2) Saving in C.\ directly is always a bad idea. 3) Please add tags C# and/or Interop tags.

Comment: Debug the code and check what is the value of `macro` in `excelApplication.Run(macro,
Type.Missing...`

Comment: Unless your workbook name contains no spaces, you need to enclose it in single quotes when you build the macro name string for `Run` to use.

Comment: @Rory yes exact , you're awesome .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified your code little bit and it works just fine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            VBIDE.VBComponent newStandardModule;
            VBIDE.CodeModule codeModule;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            const string excelFile = @"C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Sid.xlsm";

            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;

            // Open a File
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile, misValue, 
                         misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
                         misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                         misValue, misValue, misValue);

            newStandardModule = xlWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(
                                VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

            codeModule = newStandardModule.CodeModule;

            // add vba code to module
            var lineNum = codeModule.CountOfLines + 1;

            var macroName = "test";

            var codeText = "Sub " + macroName + "()" + "\r\n";
            codeText +=    "    Dim xsheet As Worksheet" + "\r\n";
            codeText +=    "    For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" + "\r\n";
            codeText +=    "        xsheet.UsedRange.Value = xsheet.UsedRange.Value" + "\r\n";
            codeText +=    "    Next xsheet" + "\r\n";
            codeText +=    "End Sub";

            codeModule.InsertLines(lineNum, codeText);
            xlWorkBook.Save();

            // run the macro
            var macro = string.Format("{0}!{1}.{2}", xlWorkBook.Name, newStandardModule.Name, macroName);
            xlexcel.Run(macro,misValue, misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue, misValue,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,   misValue, misValue, misValue,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,  misValue, misValue, misValue,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```